# Getting "Undefined Javascript/css file" while using grunt to build source in angular project

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, gruntjs

While trying to run my angular project, I used the following command

```
grunt --force
```

It automatically build a "dist" folder from where I am trying to run app pointing to "index.html"

But in index .html, the source of files created by grunt is giving "undefined file" error, and giving a 404 while running in browser.

The follwoing is my project structure.

```
myapp
app
dist
 scripts
   scripts.2ffedse.js
 styles
   main.f1de5fr6.css
 index.html
```

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.f1de5fr6.css"> --->giving error here

<div>
<!--  html code -->
</div>
<script src="scripts/scripts.2ffedfse.js"></script> -->giving error here
```

though the files are present in the src location it is still giving error.

The follwing is from cmd

```
/myapp/dist$ http-server -o
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Can someone help me understand what exactly is this error with grunt.

Comment: Are you sure you open `dist/index.html` and not another index.html in your browser?

Comment: I am starting server from dist folder ... and opening host in my server
/myapp/dist$ http-server -o
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: If you can see the files in the app source folder, this is not a Grunt problem. Does going to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/styles/` shows anything?